# PropertyChanged in WindowsPhone 8 silverlight

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8

i'm developing an app for Windows Phone 8 and using a LongListSelector  very close to the DataBound sample application that Microsoft has.

What i want to do: when i tap an item, i want it to show a checkmark at the end of the line. Tap it again and the checkmark will disappear.

At the moment, i'm creating an item from the DB and check if my property is true. If it's true, i'm showing the checkmark, else i'm not.

How can i notify the LongListSelector that the item's property has changed and display the icon?

One way I was thinking is modify the item's property, remember the index, remove the view from the LongListSelector, add the item and move it to my desired index. But i think there is a much simpler and cleaner way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using DataBinding and have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged completely top-down?

Comment: Yes, thanks, i am and implemented INotify, but couldn't find a good example on hos to use it.